# How to communicate between tabhost and new actvities

Tags: android, android-widget, android-tabhost

I just encountered a problem in my android application.  There are five tabs in my tabhost, which can hold five activities. If one of them jumps to another activity (not in tabhost), the tabhost is missing, but I want all of my activities to display in tabhost.

How can I do this and how do I get/put data between two activities in tabhost?

Comment: please go through the link, may this will help & serves your need [Example](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) inside your TabHost to achieve this (i.e. the content shown for an individual tab is an ActivityGroup)